# Package is not found on source

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

We're using a local Nuget feed structured as hierarchical folders.

I have this error from Nuget Package Manager 3.5.0.1737 under Visual Studio 2015 :

**\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew: Package 'Configuration.WebAPI.Client.1.0.16405.2-alpha' is not found on source '\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew'.**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       NuGet Package restore failed for project Softs\FrontEnd\Web.FormHost: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to find version '1.0.16405.2-alpha' of package 'Configuration.WebAPI.Client'.
  \\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew: Package 'Configuration.WebAPI.Client.1.0.16405.2-alpha' is not found on source '\\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Configuration.WebAPI.Client.1.0.16405.2-alpha' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageDownloader.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<RestorePackageAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageRestoreManager.<RestorePackageAsync>d__39.MoveNext().          0
```

As you can see, the package **'Configuration.WebAPI.Client.1.0.16405.2-alpha'** is not found.

This nuget has been published in the local feed and added in the designated project by one of my coworker.

This is the first time I have that kind of message. I upgraded to this specific version of Nuget Package Manager last week.

The nuget is present in the directory structure.

[image]

On interresting point is that Process Monitor show NO activity on this directory. It shows activity on other nuget folders though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rolled back the extension to the 3.4.4.1321 version, and it is now working fine.

I did not paid attention to the fact that the 3.5.0.1737 is a beta version.

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolve this issue by rolled back the extension. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message find the package under “\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew”, but your package is stored under “\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew\Configuration.WebAPI.Client\1.0.16405.2-alpha”. I have check in both NuGet Pacakge Manager 3.5.0.1737 and previous version of NuGet Package Manager, they could not find the package from “\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew”.

So please check your package source configuration in Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Source, make sure the source URL set as “\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew\Configuration.WebAPI.Client\1.0.16405.2-alpha”. At least you need to set the URL to “\hd\teamshare\NugetsNew\Configuration.WebAPI.Client”, since the NuGet Package Manager could find packages from the source URL and the first subfolder of the URL.

Comment: I'm using a hierarchical folder structure. All my nugets are stored like this one that could not be found. This is perfectly fine.